# How can one draw a segment of a sphere with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replace the black plan with a segment of a sphere using tikz :

[image: continuation pseudo arclength]

The sphere would be of centre `H(Y_i)` and radius `||H(Y_i) , H(Y_i+1^0)||` on which will lie all the points from `k=0` (green point) to `k` (blue point) (=> corresponding to an arc of a circle in the plan designated by the axis system in the upper left corner).

Any propositions using tikz to add a part of a sphere would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update with sphere segment answers**

With the help of @marmot :

[image: marmot_answer_improvement]

Thanks again for this nice rendering.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! to my opinion your question (as is) is to broad and  type do-it-for-me, so it will probably will be closed .... please show us, what you try so far.

Comment: Your own pic looks great! (In principle you could add ball shading by clipping the path and then shade a full sphere using `\shade[ball color=...]...`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of this post is to define a style that draws a part of a sphere. More specifically, it will draw a segment in which the latitude and longitude are in a certain range. Drawing this segment is then as simple as saying

```
\draw[thin,fill=white,fill opacity=0.6,
 sphere segment={phi from 60 to 120 and theta from -10 to 50 and radius 4}];
```

where phi and theta are the longitude and latitude parameters.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d} 
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner
sep=1pt},sphere segment/.style args={%
phi from #1 to #2 and theta from #3 to #4 and radius #5}{insert path={%
 plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=#2:#1] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=#5,longitude=\x,latitude=#3)
 -- plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=#3:#4] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=#5,longitude=#1,latitude=\x)
 --plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=#1:#2] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=#5,longitude=\x,latitude=#4)
 -- plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=#4:#3] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=#5,longitude=#2,latitude=\x)}},
>=stealth,declare function={f(\x)=exp(-2+0.5*\x);}] 
 \draw[thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 \draw[thick,orange] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=0:4] ({\x},0,{f(\x)});
 % note: this domain is an approximation, it should really be 
 % from 0 to xmax where xmax is the solution of x^2+f(x)^2=4^2
 \draw[thin,fill=white,fill opacity=0.6,
 sphere segment={phi from 60 to 120 and theta from -10 to 50 and radius 4}] ; 
 \draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (6,0,0);
 \draw[thick,orange] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=4:6] ({\x},0,{f(\x)});
 % should be xmax:6
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a version for Henri Menke, who suggested the syntax

```
\clip[sphere segment={r=4, phi=60:120, theta=-10:50}];
```

The clip is used to cut out a segment of a sphere. (A sphere is just a circle in `tdplot_screen_coordinate` since the orthographic projection of any sphere is a circle in the screen coordinates. Most likely I reinvented some things...)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d} 
\tikzset{3d stuff/.is family,
3d stuff/.cd,
parse domain/.code args={#1:#2}{\def\xmin{#1}\def\xmax{#2}},
sphere segment/.is family,
sphere segment/.cd,
r/.initial=1, 
phi/.initial=0:30, 
theta/.initial=0:30
}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner
sep=1pt},sphere segment/.style={
/utils/exec=\tikzset{3d stuff/sphere segment/.cd,#1}%
\pgfkeys{/tikz/3d stuff/parse domain/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/phi}}
\edef\phimin{\xmin}
\edef\phimax{\xmax}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/3d stuff/parse domain/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/theta}}
\edef\thetamin{\xmin}
\edef\thetamax{\xmax},
insert path={%
plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\phimax:\phimin] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/r},
  longitude=\x,latitude=\thetamin)
-- plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\thetamin:\thetamax] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/r},
 longitude=\phimin,latitude=\x)
--plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\phimin:\phimax] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/r},
 longitude=\x,latitude=\thetamax)
-- plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\thetamax:\thetamin] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/sphere segment/r},
 longitude=\phimax,latitude=\x) --cycle}},
>=stealth,declare function={f(\x)=exp(-2+0.5*\x);}] 
 \draw[thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 \draw[thick,orange] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=0:4] ({\x},0,{f(\x)});
 % note: this domain is an approximation, it should really be 
 % from 0 to xmax where xmax is the solution of x^2+f(x)^2=4^2
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[sphere segment={r=4, phi=60:120, theta=-10:50}]; 
  \shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color=gray!30,opacity=0.5] 
   (0,0) circle[radius=4];
 \end{scope} 
 \draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (6,0,0);
 \draw[thick,orange] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=4:6] ({\x},0,{f(\x)});
 % should be xmax:6
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @marmot, I should have just ask it with MWE in the first time, that wasn't intended to be the whole picture but more like what you just did,  my bad...

Comment: @Yacola No worries and glad to hear that this goes in the right direction.

Comment: A nicer syntax would be `sphere segment={r=4, phi=60:120, theta=-10:50}` in my opinion.

Comment: @HenriMenke Done. Note that one does not only need the domain but also explicitly the lower and upper ends (otherwise, yes, I would just have inserted the pgfkeys...).